# WordPress. Неверно отображается плагин

Tags: wordpress, плагин, wp-plugin, carousel

Суть проблемы в том что не могу установить на главную страницу сайта ни один плагин со слайдером. Я использую Carousel Slider. После создания слайдера добавил шорткод на страницу, позже при помощи конструкции ниже, добавил слайдер на страницу. Сам слайдер не отображается, а подгружаются картинки в столбик с описанием. Подумал что не верно подключил jquery, но он работает, так что с этим все должно быть нормально.

Конструкция в index.php

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode("[carousel_slide id='290']");?>
```

Comment: Непонятно зачем столько телодвижений (надо просто вставить шорткод. Один раз), но см ошибки яваскрипта в консоли браузера.

Comment: Согласен, плюс необходимо проверить корректность подключения CSS слайдера. Как правило всё что "плывёт" во фронт-энде дело рук либо JS, либо CSS.